# Autocommit example in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to follow an example as below, but I get a different result, being that the second select in session A returns the new row inserted by Session B.

The example is from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-consistent-read.html. I am using 5.5.

```
           Session A              Session B

           SET autocommit=0;      SET autocommit=0;
time
|          SELECT * FROM t;
|          empty set
|                                 INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 2);
|
v          SELECT * FROM t;
           empty set
                                  COMMIT;

           SELECT * FROM t;
           empty set

           COMMIT;

           SELECT * FROM t;
           ---------------------
           |    1    |    2    |
           ---------------------
           1 row in set
```

**Update**
I changed in both session A and B for transaction as below, but the problem still exists.

```
SET autocommit=0;   -- I think this line is redundant given the line below 
set transaction isolation level read committed;
start transaction;
```

Any idea?

Comment: You might want to explicitly set [`isolation level`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed) as `READ COMMITTED` might be implied in your version of MySQL (i am not sure, thats just an idea, and you asked for one ;) )

Comment: I tried that, but not working. Please see my update.

Comment: `READ COMMITTED` is exactly the behavior you're observing ;) see other isolation levels...

Comment: It is repeatable read by default in MySQL 5.5+. Read committed should prevent session A reading session B's changes before session B's commit.